# How would you create a page like WP's Mail app's Compose screen?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone

I'm new to WP dev (and pretty much C# and Silverlight in general) and I've been playing with Textboxes. I found pretty quickly that you can't really scroll a `TextBox` control.

I've seen some solutions to this on various blogs and StackOverflow posts, and the most popular one seems to be to embed the `TextBox` in a `ScrollViewer`, then use some code to make the current input line always visible, like this:

```
scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(textBox.ActualHeight);
```

This works okay if you have a relatively small `TextBox`, but if you want to make one that takes up quite a bit of space, you run into problems where the keyboard covers up the bottom section, you can't scroll to the top unless you manually move the cursor up there, etc.

Now the Compose page of the Mail application seems to do this perfectly: a nice big space for text entry where the keyboard never blocks the input, you can freely scroll through the entire pane, it just works really. I've tried various combinations of scrollviewers and textboxes but I haven't had any success in matching its behavior.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default apps are not written in C# using controls accessible in SDK or on the net. 
Replication of mail viewer and composer has been tried before rather un-successfully. (Based on similar posts of AppHub - old WP7 forum)

Comment: Ah, okay then. That's really unfortunate. I'm starting to even notice now in other WP apps that the textboxes often have quirks.